# Maps(Mapbox) resulting in too much output process

Tags: android, mapbox, android-logcat, mapquest

```
10-17 15:55:19.865 28132-28132/com.D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativeGetZoom
10-17 15:55:19.875 28132-28132/com. D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativeGetMetersPerPixelAtLatitude
10-17 15:55:19.885 28132-28132/com.D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativePixelForLatLng
10-17 15:55:19.885 28132-28132/com. D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativeGetZoom
10-17 15:55:19.885 28132-28132/com. D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativeGetMetersPerPixelAtLatitude
10-17 15:55:19.895 28132-28132/com.D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativePixelForLatLng
10-17 15:55:19.905 28132-28132/com. D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativeGetZoom
10-17 15:55:19.905 28132-28132/com. D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativeGetMetersPerPixelAtLatitude
10-17 15:55:19.915 28132-28132/com.r D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativePixelForLatLng
10-17 15:55:19.915 28132-28132/com. D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativeGetZoom
10-17 15:55:19.915 28132-28132/com.D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativeGetMetersPerPixelAtLatitude
10-17 15:55:19.935 28132-28132/com. D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativePixelForLatLng
10-17 15:55:19.935 28132-28132/com. D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativeGetZoom
10-17 15:55:19.935 28132-28132/com. D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativeGetMetersPerPixelAtLatitude
10-17 15:55:19.945 28132-28132/com.D/mbgl: [JNI]: nativePixelForLatLng
```

My logcat is filled with these lines, I'm using Maps from MapBox.
Its hard to check logs because its filled with these lines.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been working on reducing the log output of our SDK. One of the ideas we have is using Timber (see [this issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/6372)). You can try upgrading to either the latest 4.2.0-beta.3 or SNAPSHOT (built nightly) which has removed some of this output.

Comment: How do I use this 4.2.0-beta.3 on gradle? Just like this one? 
`com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.0-beta.3@aar`

Comment: why would you want to downgrade for this? this answer's rather old and the amount of output inside the SDK should be greatly reduced in 5.0.0 as long as you don't plant timber inside your application object.